# How to call API when app is terminated in push notifcation iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

We are working on push notification. We need to call the web service when we get a notification in active, background, foreground and terminated. But when we terminated the app we get a notification but can’t able to call the web service. The reason for calling the web service is to identify the message was received for a mobile app.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        if ( application.applicationState == .inactive || application.applicationState == .background ) {
                **// Need to call API**
        }
    }
```

**Is any other way to identify the message  was delivered in mobile app in the server side?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **As per Apple guidelines, you can get push notification for the background as well as on foreground state but when it comes to
>   Terminate state apple don't allow you to automatically open the app or
>   do any kind of operation unless you launch the app through notification.**

*Though you can handle notification during the Terminated state using Launch Options at the time of app launch.*

**Coding Example:**

**In your AppDelegate.swift import firebase library**

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseInstanceID
import FirebaseMessaging
import UserNotifications
```

**Whenever app launch register for push notification service, add the following lines of code into your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    registerForPushNotifications(application: application)
    handleNotificationWhenAppIsKilled(launchOptions)
    return true
}

func handleNotificationWhenAppIsKilled(_ launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) {
    // Check if launched from the remote notification and application is close
    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any] {
        // Handle your app navigation accordingly and update the webservice as per information on the app.
    }
}
```

**Add extension methods of appDelegate to register for remote notification and to get device token from APNS**

```
//MARK: - Notifications related...
extension AppDelegate {
    func registerForPushNotifications(application: UIApplication) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM
            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
        let savedAPNSToken = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedAPNSToken") as? String
        if savedAPNSToken != token {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "savedAPNSToken")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

}
```

**Use the following methods of notificationCenter to handle notification in the foreground and background states :**

```
// MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        completionHandler([.alert])
    }


    /// Handle tap on the notification banner
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - center: Notification Center
    ///   - response: Notification response
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        completionHandler()
    }
```

**Firebase token renewel:**

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
        let savedFCMToken = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "savedFCMToken") as? String
        if savedFCMToken != fcmToken {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(fcmToken, forKey: "savedFCMToken")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            // Update FCMToken to server by doing API call...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to get a notifcation when open the app. I want to get a notification when it's in inactive state.

Comment: @HarikarthickK what do you mean by Inactive state whether it killed state or background??

Comment: @HarikarthickK I am updating my answer It will definitely help you get a notification in the killed state. Are you using Firebase for notification??

Comment: @HarikarthickK have look I have updated my answer. It's, particularly for firebase. I used it in my app. it's working fine

Comment: @HarikarthickK Don't forget to add background modes ON in your app's capabilities.

Comment: It's worked perfectly on iOS 11+ devices. But when the app is in background state we are not receiving notifications in iOS 10 devices.

Comment: which method call or how can i update my badge when application Terminated? - Jarvis The Avanger

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below this is what you require.

https://samwize.com/2015/08/07/how-to-handle-remote-notification-with-background-mode-enabled/

You need to activate background mode for push notification. The full process is been explained in the above article.

Comment: This article is badly out of date with the inclusion of Service Extensions in 2016

Answer (score 0):

We have a option called silent notification check below link
https://medium.com/@m.imadali10/ios-silent-push-notifications-84009d57794c

Comment: Can we handle silent push on terminate state?. If yes, then how?